# Regarding html document outline

Tags: html, semantics, outline

Can I use `<h3>` element nested inside `<dt>` element in order to make logical outline in this code

```
<aside>
  <dl>
    <dt><h3>Still have questions&quest;</h3> Contact us at</dt>
    <dd>hello&commat;hardwarehackathon.com</dd>
  </dl>
</aside>
```

otherwise, it's showing "untitled ASIDE" in the document outline

Comment: for now, I'm compromising with this code                                       
            <aside>
                <h3>Still have questions&quest; Contact us at</h3>
                <p>hello&commat;hardwarehackathon.com</p>                
            </aside>

Comment: `<h3>Still have questions&quest;</h3> Contact us at` is certainly not a _term_ that would deserve or need a _definition_. Your "compromise" is certainly better IMHO, because it doesn't (ab-)use a definition list for content that clearly has no place being in one. I would put "Contact us at" at the beginning of the paragraph though, not at the end of the headline.

Comment: And for crying out loud, please use a `mailto:` link or at least properly write out the e-mail address, so that selecting it has it ready to be used without further manipulation. All this does is hinder legitimate users from easily using the contact info; the fight against spam is a battle you should fight on the other side, meaning proper spam filtering on the receiving end.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe